# Excluding a value from a count with SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I have two temp tables set up. Table A consists of members and the businesses that they manage, multiple members can be associated to a single business.  Table B consists of just the members, their ID's, and the class of their business relationship (Retail, Business, or Retail and Business).

The query I need to come up with is to find out which of those members from Table B do not have a Retail relationship at all.  Unfortunately a simple `where` clause will not suffice, because a member may have multiple relationships, i.e. John Doe has a Retail AND Business relationship, or possibly all three.

I can try `SELECT * FROM B WHERE class='Business'` which would pull all members who have Business relationships listed in the column, but on the flip side when I say `WHERE class = 'Retail'`, it would bring in all those members who have a Business relationship as well. I want to exclude anyone from my count who doesn't have a retail relationship at all, so from my example above, John Doe would not be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationships in Table B that are retail start with "Retail..." so we can select these using `LIKE 'Retail%'` then exclude them from the members we select from Table A by using `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE MemberID NOT IN
    (SELECT MemberID FROM TableB WHERE class LIKE 'Retail%')
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris the query looks great, but when I run the query, i'm not getting any results. Which would mean there's truly no one in the tables with no Retail relationships?

Comment: @seequill Maybe there isn't? Try a count of those with retail relationships (exclude the NOT): `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID) FROM TableB WHERE MemberID IN (SELECT MemberID FROM TableB WHERE class LIKE 'Retail%')` and compare this to how many unique MemberIDs you have: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID) FROM TableB`. If they are the same, then everyone has a retail relationship.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the retail relationship from a member, re-run the query and see if that member now turns up (assuming you have a test database to play with - don't do this in the live production database).

Comment: A few words to explain the SQL code might be helpful for posterity and to toss a bone to those who are not familiar with `LIKE`/subqueries.

Comment: Yes, a distinct count of all members yields the same number as the count of members with a retail relationship.  I think my logic has been mixed up somewhere, because my manager mentioned that there were instances where this wasn't the case.  I'm going to remove the retail relationship from a member in a temp table and see if that query pulls him up.

Comment: @seequill I was assuming that everyone in table A had a relationship in table B but maybe there are members in table A that have no relationship at all and these are the ones your manager wants to see? I'll adjust the query to take that into account.

Comment: So, just an update on this.  I deleted the retail relationship from a specific member in my temp table (Table B), and re-ran your query and he popped up.  I then re-ran all my queries to populate both temp tables, and re-ran your query just to check, and somehow ~5000 members showed up.  I'm baffled.

Comment: @seequill Weird, but glad you got it sorted! If this solved your problem, please click the Accept as answer button so future readers know that this solution works.

Comment: @ChrisLatta Thanks! If I wanted to do further analysis on members who had a retail relationship, would I just do the opposite of the query you had provided, put it in a temp table then join it to the table I need and replicate it?  For example, of those members with retail relationships I want to see if they have distinctly only used cash, debit, or credit in the past. `Select blah blah from TempTableC C inner join blah blah blah where C.PartyID not in (select c.partyid from TempTableC where PayType in 'Cash')` Which would result in member who have never used cash, correct?

Comment: @seequill Yes, it would show those customers who had never used cash but will also show those customers that have never bought anything at all - they don't have a cash transaction because they don't have any transactions. That may not be a problem - I imagine they are in a retail relationship because they are doing transactions, so there may not be an issue, or you might want to see them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any test data, but give this a try

```
Select
    ta.*
From seequillTableA as ta
Left Join   
    (Select
        ID
        , COUNT(*) as cntRetail
    From seequillTableB
    Where Class <> 'Retail' AND Class <> 'Retail and Business'
    Group By ID
    Having COUNT(*) = 0
    ) as tb
On ta.ID = tb.ID
Where tb.cntRetail = 0
```

Comment: I like Chris' solution better

Comment: Thanks! it's always interesting to see another way of tackling the problem.  Therein lies the problem with SQL.